# Using DataTrigger to change colour of ListView depending on value returned in ItemSource

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a XAML page with a listview. What I want to do is when the value of the first column "NumType" equals "S" the background colour for that row is set to a different colour.

I have been looking at using DataTriggers, but I'm not sure if this is the way to go.

Below is the code that I currently have.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MobileWarehouseXamarin.Controls"
             xmlns:ef="clr-namespace:MobileWarehouseXamarin.Effects"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"    
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             x:Class="MobileWarehouseXamarin.Controls.MW_AdjustmentsAwaiting_0"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MobileWarehouseXamarin.ViewModels;assembly=MobileWarehouseXamarin"
             x:Name="this"
             RowSpacing="0"
             ColumnSpacing="0"
             Padding="5,0,5,0">


    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>-->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Location" Style="{StaticResource KeyValueSmall_Key}" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Barcode" Style="{StaticResource KeyValueSmall_Key}" />
        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="User" Style="{StaticResource KeyValueSmall_Key}" />
        <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="Date" Style="{StaticResource KeyValueSmall_Key}" />
        <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="Reason" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockLabel}" />-->
    </Grid>

    <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="gridViewAwaitingAdjustmentDetails"  ItemsSource="{Binding AwaitingAdjustment}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAdjustment, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <!--Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemHighlighted}">-->
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                            <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="300" />-->
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding NumType}" Style="{StaticResource KeyValueSmall_Value}" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding LocationCode}" Style="{StaticResource KeyValueSmall_Value}" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{Binding Barcode}" Style="{StaticResource KeyValueSmall_Value}" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding UserName}" Style="{StaticResource KeyValueSmall_Value}" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{Binding PickingAdjustementDate}" Style="{StaticResource KeyValueSmall_Value}" Margin="0,0,0,0" />

                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be very much appreciated

I have looked at using the DataTrigger, but not sure how to go about it or would I be better off looking at Template Selectors?

Comment: You're effectively seeking advice on the best option. This site is more about solving actual development problems. If you know how to do it, choose one way and if it doesn't feel right, try out another one. Both DataTriggers and DataTemplates valid approaches here.

Comment: *"not sure how to go about it"*: find the closest example you can, and attempt to write the code. When you get stuck, search for previous questions, using words relevant to what you are doing. If don't find one, add that code to question, and point out the exact step you are stuck on. For example, perhaps you write a Data Trigger, but can't get the color to change. Then focus on that detail, both when searching, and when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this.

A simple method is to add a field to the item of your `ListView` and bind it to the                         `BackgroundColor` of the item, for example:

```
public Color BgColor { get; set; } = Color.Yellow;
```

I created a simple demo and achieved this function,you can refer to the following code:

**Item.cs**

```
public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public Color BgColor { get; set; } = Color.Yellow;

        private string _numType;
        public string NumType
        {
            get => _numType;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _numType, value);

                setBgColor();// set BgColor
            }
        }

        private void setBgColor()
        {
            if (NumType != null && NumType.Equals("S")) {
                BgColor = Color.Green;
            }
        }

        public string LocationCode { get; set; }

        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string PickingAdjustementDate { get; set; }


        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }


        public MyViewModel() { 
         Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

            Items.Add( new Item { NumType = "S" , LocationCode = "0001"});
            Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "M", LocationCode = "0002" });
            Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "L", LocationCode = "0003" });

        }
    }
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:xamlistviewapp131="clr-namespace:XamListViewApp131"
             x:Class="XamListViewApp131.MainPage">


    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <xamlistviewapp131:MyViewModel></xamlistviewapp131:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="gridViewAwaitingAdjustmentDetails"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  >
            <!--Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemHighlighted}">-->
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColor}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="300" />-->
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding NumType}" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding LocationCode}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{Binding Barcode}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding UserName}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{Binding PickingAdjustementDate}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" />

                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```